# Windows 10: Create shortcut to Windows Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, shortcuts

How can I create file shortcut (.lnk) to Windows Update?

On Windows 7, I could just drag and drop the icon from the address bar, but Microsoft removed this feature on Windows 10.

My intention is to then move it to [Start10](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/), and if that doesn't work, then into a folder on the desktop which contains some administrative tasks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Procedure

1. Right click on Desktop > Choose New > Shortcut.

[image: desktop-new-context-menu]

2. There will be a dialog box "What item would you like to create a shortcut for?"
   Type the following command in the location box.

```
control /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate
```

[image: new-shortcut-dialog-box]

3. Enter the name of the shortcut file. Shortcut will be placed in Desktop.

**Source:** [LifeWire: Command Line Commands for Control Panel Applets](https://www.lifewire.com/command-line-commands-for-control-panel-applets-2626060)

Comment: Accepted answer because it is also compatible with Windows 7

Comment: Downvoters, please clarify the cause to downvote. It will help me to understand my mistake (if any).

Comment: I did not downvote anyone here. What I did was I accepted your answer, then removed the accept, then re-added it. Maybe that also showed you some negative points because of the removal? But if I had a criticism to make with your answer, then it would be the borderless images; so much confusing white space; yet to me this is no reason for downvoting whatsoever.

Comment: I can't speak for the person who downvoted your answer, but it is notable that the OP emphasized that this is the *"Accepted answer because it is also compatible with Windows 7"* although that was **not** one of the criteria in the original question (nor was Windows 7 one of the tags, either).  Just something to consider.

Answer (score 5):

Create a shortcut to `ms-settings:windowsupdate`

There's a complete list of all the Settings URIs here: [ms-settings: URI scheme reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. This would have been my preferred answer, if Biswapriyo's answer wouldn't also be compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: I beautified the url in this answer.  However, this URI scheme functionality varies based on the Windows SKU and/or version, but the page itself specifies any specific limitations.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click > **New** > **Shortcut**
2. **Location:** `ms-settings:windowsupdate` > *Next*
3. **Name:** Windows Update > *Finish*